# Generate .asoundrc

Tags: audio, alsa

Is there any way to generate .asoundrc?
I know that by default this file does not exist and system generates one on the go like Xorg does. But is there any way to see how the content will look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user's `~/.asoundrc` file is a way to override the default configuration (in `/usr/share/alsa/`) or the machine configuration (in `/etc/asound.conf`).

Normally, it is not necessary to change this configuration.
And if it is, you have to write it by hand.

The official documentation:

- [Configuration files](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/conf.html)
- [Runtime arguments in configuration files](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/confarg.html)
- [Runtime functions in configuration files](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/conffunc.html)
- [Hooks in configuration files](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/confhooks.html)
- [PCM (digital audio) plugins](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html)

… is rather useless.
Usually, you try to find [some examples](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) on the internet.

Comment: thanks, i couldn't find that file.

I'm trying to do something, that will have few pcm, like i did in pulseaudio with null-sinks to separate VoIP apps from the rest of the sounds and them mix it down to master output.